# Strapi build for production hangs when using Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, strapi

I'm using a `Dockerfile` for deploying a strapi app on production.

Everything works perfectly when starting with node.js runtime environment (using `yarn develop`)

```
One more thing...
Create your first administrator  by going to the administration panel at:

┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ http://localhost:1337/admin │
└─────────────────────────────┘

[2021-01-21T11:06:49.724Z] debug HEAD /admin (9 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:06:49.726Z] info ⏳ Opening the admin panel...
[2021-01-21T11:06:50.477Z] debug GET /admin (3 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:06:50.640Z] debug GET /admin/runtime~main.24109598.js (6 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:06:50.647Z] debug GET /admin/main.04cf6eef.chunk.js (2 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:06:51.871Z] debug GET /admin/init (28 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:06:51.938Z] debug GET /admin/842e7845f3f8e943ff712a39617b6b70.svg (2 ms) 200
```

This is the `Dockerfile` that I'm using:

```
FROM strapi/base
WORKDIR /strapi
COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 1337
RUN yarn start
```

After building and trying to run the docker image, it hangs on this infinitely and there is no option to get it working

```
One more thing...
Create your first administrator  by going to the administration panel at:

┌───────────────────────────┐
│ http://0.0.0.0:1337/admin │
└───────────────────────────┘

[2021-01-21T11:01:24.578Z] debug HEAD /admin (17 ms) 200
[2021-01-21T11:01:24.584Z] info ⏳ Opening the admin panel...
```

This is the `.env` file that works perfectly with the node.js environment

```
PORT=1337
DATABASE_URI=<connection-string>
```

And this is the command I'm using to check if it runs:

```
docker build -t can/api . && docker run --rm -p 1337:1337 can/api
```

When I try to set the `HOST` manually, it says this:

```
---> Running in 6a1d5711fe55
yarn run v1.22.5
$ strapi start
[2021-01-21T11:15:44.774Z] error Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.0.19:1337
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1299:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1364:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is located the DB?

Comment: It's on azure. But as I said, it works perfectly when trying to connect from node runtime env, but not when building with docker

I suppose it's a host problem, and that's why I tried to set manually the host, but it does not work either

Answer (score 3):

My docker file is slightly different I do copy the env into the folder:

```
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./
COPY ./.env ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV ENV_PATH /app/.env
 
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

These are the commands I do use to deploy it using docker

`docker build -t stayactivebackend .`

`docker run -ti -d -p 1337:1337 -v /var/www/strapiRepositoryPath/public/uploads:/app/public/uploads --network=host stayactivebackend:latest`

Comment: Is this local directory i.e `/var/www/strapiRepositoryPath/public/uploads` containing all uploaded files?

Comment: @SamarPanda yes that's correct, this is where the volume is set it up and it will store the upload files unless you select a different provider like AWS S3 or similar